# How to return custom messages for each functions in a DRF Viewset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having a viewset

```
class JobPostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = JobPostSerializer
    queryset = JobPost
```

How will  I return custom messages for each function? for eg. if using the get function, I have to return "listed successfully" with data, for the post "posted successfully" with data, likewise for put, patch and delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelViewSet` is inherited from `GenericAPIView` in DRF so you can override `.list()`, `.retrieve()`, `.create()`, `.update()`, `.partial_update()`, and `.destroy()` to put your custom logic and return your custom `Response`.
refer to [DRF Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for further info.

**Update:**
for customized data in Response, let's say you've created an instance of your model and have an output serializer like:

```py
output_serializer = CustomerSerializer(instance=instance, many=False, context={'request': request})
```

you can add `output_serializer.data` dict and send it like:

```py
return Response(output_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Can you please show an example for create an update. I got it for list , retrieve and destroy.